# Input textlayout error not getting the layout style

Tags: android

I am using a universal style for the `EditText` in `InputTextLayout` but when I am setting the error for `InputTextLayout`, error is not positioned properly.Please, go through the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It seems that the error message it taking the parent layout. please add your xml code.

Comment: Share your code